# Add Caldroid library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, caldroid

I have a problem when adding [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) library on Android Studio. I try many different ways to add but it won't work. I use Android Studio 0.8.2.

- First off, I created a root folder called `libraries`.
- I created a new folder `caldroid` in `/libraries`.
- Then, I pasted the downloaded files in `/libraries` folder.
- Then, I changed the following files.

settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
include 'libraries:caldroid:library'
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':libraries:caldroid:library')
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

I'm late but I faced a similar issue so I thought I'll share how I solved it.

To import an external library to Android Studio, I follow this convention:

1. Create `libs` folder inside the `app` directory. Then copy the required library files to the `libs` folder. For example, my folder contains `actionbarsherlock` and `caldroid` folders.
2. Caldroid has a library dependency that can be downloaded [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.darwinsys/hirondelle-date4j/1.5.1), you can see this in the `build.gradle` file (Also, make sure the gradle files have the correct SDK versions). Download the `hirondelle-date4j-1.5.1-sources.jar`.
3. Create `libs` folder in `app/libs/caldroid/`. Copy the `hirondelle-date4j-1.5.1-sources.jar` to `app/libs/caldroid/libs/`. You may also have to copy `android-support-v4.jar` from `-User_Home-/Android/Sdk/extras/android/support/v4/` to `app/libs/caldroid/libs/`.
4. Open `app/libs/caldroid/build.gradle` and replace `compile 'com.darwinsys:hirondelle-date4j:1.5.1'` with `compile files('libs/hirondelle-date4j-1.5.1-sources.jar')`.
5. In Android Studio, open `settings.gradle` and add this line `include ':app:libs:caldroid'`. Next, open "`build.gradle` (Module: app)" and add this line `compile project(':app:libs:caldroid')` in `dependencies`.

And that's it, now allow the gradle to "sync" or clean and build your project.

Comment: First thanx @Ravi, I am using the gradle methods for import the Android libraries. Thus I can import with one line.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line in your `dependencies` in `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.1'
```

Comment: try adding the above line ("compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:1.1.0'", that's all you need) and deleting "include 'libraries:caldroid:library'" and "compile project(':libraries:caldroid:library')"

Comment: First thanx @Bronx. When I try to add diffrent library, these methods work. But I suppose this library not fixed.